# Reducing Memory Usage in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, spree

I checked my applications, and they're running a huge amount of memory which is crashing my server.

Here's my ps :

```
  RSS COMMAND
 1560 sshd: shadyfront@pts/0
 1904 -bash
 1712 PassengerNginxHelperServer /home/shadyfront/webapps/truejersey/gems/gems/p
 8540 Passenger spawn server                                                    
  612 nginx: master process /home/shadyfront/webapps/truejersey/nginx/sbin/nginx
 1368 nginx: worker process                                                    
94796 Rails: /home/shadyfront/webapps/truejersey/True-Jersey                    
 1580 PassengerNginxHelperServer /home/shadyfront/webapps/age_of_revolt/gems/gem
 8152 Passenger spawn server                                                    
  548 nginx: master process /home/shadyfront/webapps/age_of_revolt/nginx/sbin/ng
 1240 nginx: worker process                                                    
92196 Rack: /home/shadyfront/webapps/age_of_revolt/Age-of-Revolt                
  904 ps -u shadyfront -o rss,command
```

Is this abnormally large for an e-commerce application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux, You can use

```
 ulimit
```

http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

Not sure why it is eating your memory though.

Comment: Would  you agree though that this is an unusual amount of memory being used?

Comment: Eh, it is very high, not sure about unusual, depending on your app/load and other factors, might want to check into RubyEE, passenger isn't that helpful without it

Answer (score 0):

If your using a 64-bit OS then it's fairly normal.

```
  RSS COMMAND
89824 Rack: /var/www/vhosts/zmdev.net/zmdev  # RefineryCMS on Passenger
148216 thin server (0.0.0.0:5000)  # Redmine
238856 thin server (0.0.0.0:3000)  # Spree after a couple of weeks
140260 thin server (0.0.0.0:3000)  # Spree after a fresh reboot
```

All of these are 64-bit OSes, there are significant memory reductions using 32-bit OS

Here's the exact same Spree application running Webrick in my dev environment using 32-but Ubuntu

```
  RSS COMMAND
58904 /home/chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby script/rails s
```